# compile scala to assembly jar with SBT or gradle

Tags: scala, gradle

I asked about it yesterday, but this one is not duplicated.

I can use sbt or gradle to compile helloworld, however when it comes to some other object, I have new problems. Following is what I did can anyone tell me how to fix it?

```js
tong@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/jars$ sudo mkdir Log
tong@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/jars$ cd Log
tong@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/jars/Log$ mkdir -p src/main/scala
tong@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/jars/Log$ mkdir -p src/main/resources
tong@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/jars/Log$ mkdir -p src/test/scala
tong@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/jars/Log$ mkdir -p src/test/resources
tong@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/jars/Log$ cd src/main/scala
tong@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/jars/Log/src/main/scala$ mkdir -p com/tong/gradle
tong@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/jars/Log/src/main/scala$ vi com/tong/gradle/Log.scala

 
package org.apache.spark.h2o.utils

import water.fvec.{NewChunk, Frame, Chunk}
import water._

/** Transformation from double vector to log vector. */
class Log extends MRTask[Log] {
  override def map(c: Chunk, nc: NewChunk): Unit = {
   for (row <- 0 until c.len()) {
   nc.addNum(Math.log(c.atd(row)))
   }
  }
}

 

tong@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/jars/Log/src/main/scala$ cd ../../..
tong@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/jars/Log$ vi build.gradle

apply plugin: 'scala'
 
 jar {
        baseName = 'tong'
        version = '1.0'
        manifest {
                     attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.tong.gradle.Log' }

     }
dependencies {
  compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4'
}

tong@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/jars/Log$ gradle build
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileScala

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not find org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4.
  Required by:
      :Log:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.917 secs
```

Or its also great if you can tell me how to do it in SBT Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gradle version. For the sake of simplicity I've changed `Log.scala` class to:

```
package com.tong.gradle

object Log {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      println("Hello, world!")
   }
}
```

What was missing in `build.gradle` was `repositories` block - gradle couldn't resolve the dependencies, that's why this error occurred:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
```

So `build.gradle` script will be:

```
apply plugin: 'scala'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   compile 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4'
}

jar {
   baseName = 'tong'
   version = '1.0'
   manifest {
      attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.tong.gradle.Log' 
   }
}
```

Now if you run `gradle clean build` everything works fine but running the jar:

```
cd build/libs
java -jar tong-1.0.jar
```

gives:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   scala/Predef$     at com.tong.gradle.Log$.main(Log.scala:5)   at
>   com.tong.gradle.Log.main(Log.scala) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Predef$   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     ... 2 more

That is. The classpath for jar isn't configured. So there's a need to prepare so called *fat jar* that will include all the dependencies required at runtime. To do it add this magic line in `jar` block

```
from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
```

`gradle clean build` (notice the jar size) once again and

```
cd build/libs
java -jar tong-1.0.jar
```

and the output is:

> Hello, world!

Demo can be found [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/33310104).

Comment: before I add from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } } gradle clean build went well and create a jar for me. But when I add that line and build again I got this

Comment: tong@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/jars/Log$ gradle clean build
:clean
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileScala
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:jar
Converting class java.util.ArrayList to File using toString() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please use java.io.File, java.lang.String, java.net.URL, or java.net.URI instead.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not copy MANIFEST.MF to '/usr/local/jars/Log/build/tmp/jar/MANIFEST.MF'.

Comment: What version of gradle you use?

Comment: Gradle 1.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle build time: Monday, September 9, 2013 8:44:25 PM UTC
Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on April 8 2014
Ivy: non official version
JVM: 1.7.0_79 (Oracle Corporation 24.79-b02)
OS: Linux 3.19.0-30-generic amd64

Comment: I've tested it with gradle 2.8.

Comment: How can I update my gradle? is there a tutorial for gradle 2.8 installation?

Comment: I have installed sdkman should I just type install gradle 2.8?

Comment: Yes, I can compile helloworld. But still can not compile my Log object. It said Internal error: Failed to load org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.scala.jdk6.ZincScalaCompiler

Comment: Do you know about zinc? I download zinc-0.3.9 but dont know how and where should I install it

Comment: No, I've no idea what zinc may be. I've never used it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I will accept it as answer.!

Answer (score 4):

sbt version.

```
$ mkdir project
$ vi project/build.properties

sbt.version=0.13.9

$ vi project/plugins.sbt

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.0")

$ vi build.sbt

name                  := "tong"
version               := "1.0"
scalaVersion          := "2.10.6"
mainClass in assembly := Some("com.tong.gradle.Log")

$ sbt assembly
```

Or, if you don't need a fully contained jar including the scala-library but just want to package your code:

```
$ sbt package
```

Comment: Well, in any step before compiling or packaging ;) That is, first step or before `sbt assembly`/`sbt package`. You can run `sbt ~compile` to keep the compiler up and running while you edit your code, so you can follow up errors in your code straight away. If your program can run on its own, all you need is `sbt run`.

Comment: tong@tong-VirtualBox:/usr/local/jars/project$ sbt assembly
/usr/local/jars/project/build.sbt:4: error: not found: value assembly
mainClass in assembly := Some("com.tong.gradle.Log")
             ^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? i
[warn] Ignoring load failure: no project loaded.
[error] Not a valid command: assembly
[error] assembly
[error]         ^
Do I need to import assembly? Thanks

Comment: The assembly task is provided by the sbt-assembly plugin, which in turn is activated with the snippet shown for `project/plugins.sbt` (probably you are missing that one). You _only need assembly_ if you want to build a self-contained jar that includes the class-path. If you just want `sbt run`, you can use `mainClass in Compile` instead and forget about the sbt-assembly plugin. It sounded from your question that you required that plugin.